# scrollIntoView() not workin in Angular with {behaviour: 'smooth'}

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll

I want to achieve a smooth scrolling effect when clicking a button. The scrolling effect does actually work when I use

`document.getElementById('sectionCourses').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', inline: 'nearest'});`

but as soon as i add

`behavior: 'smooth'`

to the properties, the page is not scrolling at all. I have no idea why, the console doesn't show anything.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which browser are you using ?

The "smooth" behavior option might be not well handled depending on it, more details here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview

Comment: I experience the exact same problem in Chrome, Mozilla and Safari